# What is OS Load in Elasticsearch node stat?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch node stat API when I send a query for OS stat:

```
curl -XGET "http://esls1.ping-service.com:9200/_nodes/stats/os"
```

In the response I get a metric `load_average`:

```
"load_average": [0,0.04,0.13]
```

What does is means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the currently calculated average load of the system and how this is obtained is specific to the operating system Elasticsearch is installed on.

ES uses [Sigar](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar) to get this kind of information. The three numbers represent average loads calculated for 1 minute, 5 minutes and 15 minutes intervals.

For linux, for example, Sigar uses `/proc/loadavg` to get this information from the system. You can find more about this specific calculation in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987495/linux-proc-loadavg).

For AIX, Sigar is using [perfstat_cpu_total subroutine](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/perfstat_cputot.htm), if I'm not mistaken to get the same information.

Comment: Sigar is not used in Elasticsearch anymore since the first Beta of 2.0.0: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/12010 https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11034

Answer (score 0):

Sigar is not used in Elasticsearch anymore since the first Beta of 2.0.0: github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/12010 github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11034

since then, they switched to generic OS load metrics. similar to what you see with the `top` command. see here for an explanation what this means: https://askubuntu.com/questions/532845/what-is-system-load

beware: this means if you run ES in a docker container, the load shown will be actually from the host machine, and not from only the docker container!