# Fifth column of /proc/loadavg?

Tags: linux

I came across several discussions([linux /proc/loadavg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987495/linux-proc-loadavg)) and articles telling that the fifth column of `/proc/loadavg` is the process id of the most recent process. But I couldnot find a folder in the `/proc` filesystem with that `PID`. Also on trying `cat /proc/loadavg` the fifth column goes on increasing sequentially each time.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last value is the pid of the currently active process (while showing the contents of `/proc/loadavg`) which is likely a `cat` process

```
cat /proc/loadavg
```

which has already terminated while you are reading the results on screen.

---

**Update:**

I played around with it to prove that it is indeed the cat process. I simply used `less`, kept it open and tried to investigate the proc file system. I can only say the pid shown in `loadavg` was not the PID of `less` which I thought. Still true is what I said: the process listed there is current active process and it has been terminated already. But it seems not the PID of the `cat` process.

Comment: It only contain the last process which is executed by that file or last process which is executed by the system?

Comment: What you mean with *executed by that file* ?

Comment: What if I am not using `cat` process and open it manually.? Still I cannot find a folder with the same PID..

Comment: @Jackz Yes, I've tried that too. I simply used `less` and it was not the `less` process which I thought.. True is what I said, the process listed there is current active process and it has been terminated already. But it seems not the cat process. I'm currently playing around with some tools which can help to find out the cmdline of that process.

Answer (score 4):

The proc filesystem is a pseudo-filesystem whose files provide an interface to kernel data structures, and is usually mounted as `/proc`.
The `/proc/loadavg` provides the current calculated average load of the system.
These values represent the average system load in the last `1`, `5` and `15` minutes, the number of active / total scheduling entities (tasks) and the PID of the last created process in the system.

sample output

```
cat /proc/loadavg 
1.46              1.16            0.91            2/321             6220
 ^                  ^               ^                ^                  ^
 |                  |               |                |                  |
system load         |               |                                   
in last 1 min       |               |        Number of active/      PID of
                                    |        scheduled entities     last created process 
              system load           |               
              in last 5 min         |
                                    |
                              system load          
                              in last 15 min
```

> Also on trying `cat /proc/loadavg` the fifth column goes on increasing sequentially each time.

It represents the last created PID in the system. your cat command is also an process, so each time it varies. The process will terminate by the time you check in `/proc`.

Since so many process will be created/ deleted and the fifth field will be updated every time you do `cat /proc/loadavg`.

Comment: Even if I open the file `/prov/loadavg` , and at the same time check the proc filesystem, again I cannot find a folder with the specified PID .

Comment: What is the unit of measure of the first three numbers? A percentage, microseconds. Nobody specify this, so maybe my question is odd but it is not clear to me.