# How to make a function work in background in bash / replace text / CPU usage

Tags: multithreading, bash, monitoring, cpu-usage, ps1

I have been playing around with the bashrc and one of the thing I want to see at all time is my cpu usage in percentage. I decided to set this data in my PS1. The problem is that to have an accurate estimation of my CPU usage I need to do operations that require waiting for at least 0.5 seconds.

As a result of this, my new command line only displays at the end of the CPU calculation, 0.5 seconds later, which is really not acceptable. To deal with this I thought that I could maybe use a thread to do the CPU calculation and only display it at the end but I don't know how to do so.

One of the problem is that I display other information after CPU percentage so I don't know if it is even possible to delay the CPU display while still displaying the rest of the command line. I thought that maybe I could display a temporary string such as `??.??` and then replace it by the real value but I am not sure how to do so since if I type commands fast the position of the `??.??` can change (for example typing ls 5 times in a row very fast).

Maybe there is an even simpler solution to my problem such as calculating the CPU percentage in an other way ?

My CPU percentage calculating function:

```
function cpuf(){
    NonIdle=0;Idle=0;Total=0;TotalD=0;Idled=0
    NonIdle=$((`cat /proc/stat | awk '/^cpu / {print$2+$3+$4+$7+$8+$9}'` - $NonIdle))
    Idle=$((`cat /proc/stat | awk '/^cpu / {print$5+$6}'` - $Idle))
    sleep 0.5
    NonIdle=$((`cat /proc/stat | awk '/^cpu / {print$2+$3+$4+$7+$8+$9}'` - $NonIdle))
    Idle=$((`cat /proc/stat | awk '/^cpu / {print$5+$6}'` - $Idle))
    Total=$((Idle+NonIdle))
    CPU=$(((Total-Idle)/Total))
    echo `echo "scale=2;($Total*100-$Idle*100)/$Total" | bc -l`
}
```

How I call it in the bashrc:

```
alias cpu="cpuf"
PS1+="(\[${MAGENTA}\]CPU $(cpu)%"
```

Comment: Have you considered storing the result in a file, such as `/tmp/cpu.log`, keep the `cpuf` running as a job (by calling `cpuf &` before creating the alias), and changing `alias cpu="cat /tmp/cpu.log"` ?

Comment: Why are you using `cat`?  `awk` takes a filename as a parameter.  The multiple child processes in your function won't do much for your CPU efficiency.

Comment: Threadp your solution seems like a very good idea, I'll check it in the morning and post a solution if it fits me, thank you. cdarke, you're very right I will change that too.

Comment: Note that if you opt by using the file solution, you may want to keep the job out of the `.bashrc` to prevent multiple jobs doing the same thing. If you really want to start that job from the `.bashrc`, remember to check if it's already running before starting a new one. (You should also consider to use a filename such as /tmp/cpu_<username>.log if a multi-user scenario is expected... but in this case, I really recommend a single [small] service to update the file, common to all users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel here, linux already takes care of capturing system stats in `/proc/loadavg`.  The first number is average load in the last minute across all cpus, so we just need to divide by the number of cpus, which we can determine by reading `/proc/cpuinfo`.  Rolling this into `.bashrc` we get:

**.bashrc**

```
...
# My fancy prompt, adjust as you like...
FANCY_PROMPT="$GREEN\u$YELLOW@\h:$PURPLE\w$BLUE$ $RESET"

CPUS=$( grep -c bogomips /proc/cpuinfo )

_prompt_command() {
    LOAD_AVG_1_MIN=$( cut -d ' ' -f 1 /proc/loadavg )
    PERCENT=$( echo "scale=0; $LOAD_AVG_1_MIN * 100 / $CPUS" | bc -l )
    PS1="CPU $PERCENT% $FANCY_PROMPT"
    true
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="_prompt_command"
```

**In Use:**

[image]

[SO linux /proc/loadavg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987495/linux-proc-loadavg)

Comment: This too suffers from a [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html). `grep` is perfectly capable of reading `/proc/cpuinfo` itself, though you can also get rid of the `wc -l` by substituting `grep -c`; and the `cut` and `bc` combo might be more efficient if you refactored to a simple Awk script.

Comment: Removed useless cat.

Comment: I fixed the other one; please review.

Comment: Thanks.  No more cats... 

Comment: Another problematic antipattern is the use of upper case in user variables, but I think we can live with that here.

Comment: I tried your solution and I get a very different number. When my function gives me 3.77% yours is giving me 13%. Is your way more accurate and mine off ?

Comment: Actually, after some testing the numbers are pretty close if you take into account the delay. Can you tell me if my calculation is accurate ? If it is I might implement it anyway to be able to see CPU usage change in the second rather than in 45 seconds.

Comment: And by the way, why aren't you greping the cpu cores data in /proc/cpuinfo rather than counting bogomips ?

Comment: If you grep for `cpu`, you will get lots of matches, if you grep for `bogomips`, you get one match per cpu.

Comment: Using /proc/cpuinfo, the data is delayed by up to a second.  That should be good enough for most purposes.  The benefit is not waiting 0.5 second for your function to return before seeing a bash prompt, as well as not overly complicating your system by introducing yet another service.