# How to find number of kernels in Mac OS X and Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, macos, linux-kernel, kernel

A very simple question as the title says.

I know the difference between kernel and OS, but when I do 
`cat /proc/loadavg` on my cluster, it shows me this `0.29 0.20 0.13 1/3006 48449`.
Then I did some research [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987495/linux-proc-loadavg) and [link2](http://www.loadavg.com/2012/01/what-is-loadavg/) which explain me what those five numbers mean.

Then I was trying to find how many kernels that I have on my single server and on my Mac OS X.

I tried to read my `About this Mac` -> System Report, but I'm not able to find # of kernels.

Any help please?
On both OS X and Linux and Ubuntu.

Does one OS usually just have one kernel, so it's by default that every one knows, so no explicit info is needed to be put anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is not simple, because _number of kernels_ is not well defined term. I.e. you can install multiple kernel files (`vmlinuz`), but you can load only one at a time (unless virtualization or User-mode Linux is involved).

Comment: Did you mean `cpu cores` instead `kernels`?

Comment: No, I mean kernels, CPU cores are clearly defined.

Comment: myaut answered you, the only kernel can be loaded and run at once. If you want know how many kernels are installed on your Linux system, you could look at /boot to count initrd images and even look at /boot/grub[2]/grub.cfg (or at /boot/grub/menu.lst on older Linux systems) to count kernel entries and know what number of kernels you can choose on boot. If you want to know what number of kernel you can install officially to your Ubuntu, try apt-get search linux-image-*-generic. Ubuntu includes kernel version to its package name so you can count available kernels with this command.

Comment: Thank you guys, now I understood it. Please feel free to compose an answer and post it below, I'll accept it. Thanks!